# How to implement vite js in golang?

Tags: go, vite

I'm new to Golang and I'm interested in integrating Vite.js as an asset bundler. However, I'm facing some challenges with the integration. Specifically, I'm not sure how to configure the necessary directives in Golang so that it can automatically detect which version of CSS and JS to show. I know I can show the build version of files using their names, but how do I accomplish this in dev mode? Additionally, for the production build, I would need to read the manifest.json file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have to build your project in two separate parts: backend(written in golang or other language) + frontend (vite or other framework)

Comment: Create a new file in your project directory called "vite.config.js" and add the vite configurations. Then run 'vite build' to build the assets.